# Disk cleanup not running after i cleanned the %temp%, temp, prefetch files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, temporary-files, disk-cleanup

I am completely unsure what caused this but i was cleanning my pc by using the run command and entering %temp%, temp, prefetch files and i deleted all files from those folders. I double checked to be sure if i didnt uninstall important and all were unnecessary not important.

And once i did that i used wsreset and then i cleared my network cache using ipconfig /flushdns.

After i did all of those i decided to run Disk Cleanup there after, once i clicked OK, it didnt run? i waited for 30-45 secs and it still wont appear i was freaking out/losing my mind about it and it still didn't open up though i opened Task Manager to see if it was running but it was i decided to

end the task tried to open again and nothing won't come up.

So , i finally decided just to restart my pc and try to run it. Once it booted up i ran it and everything works just as fine i was able to run it and clean it and ran storage sense after that i was nervous of course and tried to replicate what i did before and once i did all of it again and tried to run Disk Cleanup but it still worked it just ran compared to like before wherein it didnt work but it still just worked. So what do you think was it just a rare occurence of Disk Cleanup not running or it was just a one time thing and was easily repairable with a restart?

Im easily nervous when it comes to these and im eager to know what causes these due to me back then corrupting my Mac by deleting system files accidentally and due to that it was a trauma ever since.

Just to be safe, i ran sfc /scannow, DISM CheckHealth/RestoreHealth just so it will fix it permanently?

Is my Windows one way or another corrupted? or these were just a minor occurence?

I rebooted it 3 times and everytime disk cleanup works i have ensured that everything is still running and functioning as normal i ran it awhile ago and it still worked. But what might've caused this?

Comment: If DISM reported no system corruption then you have no detectable system corruption.

Comment: From what i recall it said "no component store corruption" when i ran CheckHealth. but i still did RestoreHealth anyways.

Comment: Well it was completely unnecessary.

Comment: Alright, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement "it still worked it just ran compared to like before wherein it didn't work but it still just worked"

Comment: Okay let me clarify my statement so what i basically said was "It ran just completely normal wherein just 45 secs ago it didnt open/nor function." So to summarize it just ran completely normal unlike before where it didnt open.

Comment: Though the issue never came back will it have a chance of persisting? or it was just a one time occurence just a funky ol move from Windows.

Comment: Sounds like a one time fluke, maybe some correlated process didn't fully close in memory before you opened a new instance (even though UI wise that disappeared), etc. You ran DISM, so just reboot and move on. Especially since you say it was a one time occurrence. No need in spending time chasing those down unless this machines support a critical system where perhaps for example someone's life may depend on it (e.g. hospital prior authorization, etc.).

Comment: UPDATE: I replicated it 3 times and the third time i rebooted because the icons were going blank and it was quickly resolved but then when i rebooted it the third time it was the icons were going blank i was in a middle of watching a yt video about how to fix this and then boom the screen shut off, black screen i tried to turn on my monitor and it wont it just shut off? like the pc is still running ram is recieving power but the monitor shut off completely. we tried force shutting down and 5 secs it boots up back up by itself and after attempting this 3 times it had a signal?

Comment: I tried to replicate it the 4th time and it didnt go blank it just ran perfectly normal? i then reset my icon cache and did sfc /scannow and DISM just to be safe again.



And also a memory diagnostic test and didnt have any issues too.



The issue never persisted but its fair to say i was scarred from experiencing that.

Comment: I also ran chkdsk and it said fixing drive and it fixed it hopefully

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted windows was the answer i fixed it by doing a in-place upgrade no more black screens and blank icons hopefully.